# Sqlite3 with Python

Tags: python, sqlite

My code:

```
cursor.execute("select * from PRODUCT where product_id in (?)", (ids,))
print(cursor.fetchall())
```

where `ids` is a tuple of integer values like `(2,4)`
and `product_id` are also integer values.

The error I'm getting is:

> File "c:/Users/deboparna/Desktop/college/Sem4/programming language/project/db.py", line 32, in fetchProducts
>       cursor.execute("select * from PRODUCT where product_id in (?)", (ids,))
>   sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.

Comment: **Please provide the entire error message, as well as a [mcve].**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need placeholders for each id.
You also should just use `ids` as a tuple, and not make it a tuple of a tuple.

```
placeholders = ",".join("?"*len(ids))
qry = "select * from product where product_id in ({})".format(placeholders)
cursor.execute(qry,ids)
```

Comment: thank you! it worked. but I'm still unclear on why it worked. placeholders will just give a string of comma separated question marks. which we put in the query using format. How is it different from what I was doing. was i not doing the same but put the '?' directly instead of making it a variable?

Comment: Yes, but you were only putting one question mark when you needed two. And any way dynamically generating placeholders is easier when your ids variable can presumably change :)